# Can not update product variant data in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to update price and quantity of my product variant in Shopify using cURL and php below here my code:

$url = $api_url . '/admin/api/2020-01/variants/31941936382042.json';

```
    $data_json = json_encode(
        array(
            'variants' => array(
                'id' => 4574444978266,
                'sku' => 'TEST-SKU-111',
                'price' => 20,
                'compare_at_price' => 20,
                'cost' => 20, // This price will be coming form database
                'inventory_quantity' => 10))
    );

    var_dump($data_json);


    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($response);
    curl_close($ch);
```

When I test it every time it says :

{"errors":{"variant":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}

I checked official document https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product-variant#update-2020-01 but no luck still. Can someone correct me what is the wrong I'm doing ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the key for your data array, `variants` => `variant`.

Also, note the warning at the top of the page you're referring to. You should use [Inventory APIs](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/inventory) to manager your items inventory instead of setting up `inventory_quantity` directly.

Comment: Perfect. Changing from variants => variant worked dramatically except it does not update quantity. Going to review the link you shared. Thank you.